# Partial Encryption and Serialization of Java object

Tags: java, serialization, encryption, workflow

Wanted to  encrypt part of my Java object and serialize it before sending it on wire.

More clearly, I have a workflow where each stage of it spits branch data. I want part of it(few class variables) to be encrypted and part of it to be public. I have a basic serializer that I can override to include this encryption part before serializing. Any suggestions on how to do it?

I'm thinking of having some annotation like @encypt on these varibles and before serializing it,  encrypt them. But, I am not sure how to do implement this annotation stuff. Any pointers?

```
class Foo{
    private String username;
    @encrypt
    private String password;
}

class customSerializer{

    writeExternal(Foo object){
        encrypt(object);
        serialize(encryptedObject);
    }
}

encrypt(Foo object){
    // Identify variables with @encrypt and encypt them. 
}
```

I am not sure how I should implement this 'Identify variables' part in my encrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this actual Java Serialization? If so, then when you need fine-grained control over serialization of a Java object, implement the [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface.

Comment: Thanks Sean! I know that. My question is not really about Serialization, but about how I identify variables with @encrypt annotation, encrypt and then serialize it.

Comment: Given that you'd have to do that in the object itself by implementing externalizable, I wouldn't bother. The object will know what fields need to be encrypted, so just let it do the work.